# Composition of automorphisms can not reveal what the original automorphism is?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Let $f$ be an automorphism of a finite group $G$ generated by the elements $\{g_1, g_2, \cdots, g_i\}$. $f^m$ is the automorphism $f$ composed $m$ times. i.e. $f^m = f \circ f \cdots \circ f (m \,\,times)$.

Suppose for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, the values of $f^k(g_1), f^k(g_2), \cdots , f^k(g_i)$ are computed by one person (say $A$) and these values are transmitted to another person ($B$).

Since $B$ knows only $f^k(g_1), f^k(g_2), \cdots , f^k(g_i)$ values he can not find what the automorphism $f$ is, right?

Please help me to clarify regarding the above idea.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, indeed, if $G=\{-1,1\}$ then $f^2$ is always the identity, but there are two possible automophisms $f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WoolierThanThou if we can find the possibilities of the automorphisms then we can determine the original automorphism right? How about if $A$ is using the group $G=(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_q$, where $p,q>3$ are distinct primes.

Comment: $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_q \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$. 

Suppose $G$ is generated by $<s,t>$, where $|s|=q, |t|=p$. Let $\phi_s(t)= s^{-1}ts=u$ and $\{t, \phi_s(t)\}$ form a basis of $=(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ ($|u|=p$).  $q|p^2-1$. Can you help me to argue regarding this group ?

Comment: Suppose $A$ obtain the values $\phi_{s^m}(t)=A_1$ and  $\phi_{s^m}(u)=A_2$ for some $s^m \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ and tell $B$ only the values $\{A_1, A_2, p, q\}$. Then only by using the values $\{A_1, A_2, p, q\}$ it is difficult for $B$ to obtain an idea about the original $\phi$ nor about $s,t,u$ elements even if he knows that $A$ did the computations in some semidirect product of the form $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_q$ right?

Comment: I found in a text, that when $q|p+1$ there is a unique automorphism, and if $q|p-1$ there are $\frac{q+3}{2}$ automorphisms. Then there are $\frac{q+3}{2}+1$ possibilities to check. And there are $q-1$ possibilities for $s^m$. For $t$ and $u$ how many possibilities..? If $B$ is going to check all possibilities he can write an algorithm which will run in polynomial time I think? (($\frac{q+3}{2})(q-1) \cdots$) @WoolierThanThou am I right?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou wait, what are the two automorphisms on $G=\{-1,1\}$? Any automorphism preserves the identity, so $f(1)=1$, and then an automorphism must be bijective, which forces $f(-1)=-1$. That makes the identity the unique automorphism on the group with two elements. You need at least three elements to have a nontrivial automorphism group.

Comment: @BenjaminKeilty Whoops. You are, of course, right. I was a bit fast there. Say instead, $G={1,a,b}$ $a^2=b$, $b^2=a$ and $ab=1$. Then, there is the identity automorphism and the automorphism which flips and $a$ and $b$. *They* both have the property of having order two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the value of $k$ it might be possible to find out the automorphism. If $|G| = n$, since an automorphism fixes the identity, note that the automorphisms of $G$ are naturally a subgroup of $S_{n-1}$. Hence, it could happen that there is only one element in $S_{n-1}$ satisfying $g^k = \phi$ (where $\phi$ is the automorphism you've been given). For example, in $S_3$, for a given $3$-cycle it has a unique square root.

If this doesn't work, you can look at the group of automorphisms and do a similar analysis but that might be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks @marlasca23 what do you think about the group and the argument I have mentioned in the above comments?

Comment: @Thomas Your comment is not very clear. Please write a different question explaining this better, since this is now very separate from the original question.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @marlasca23 I posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3950234/is-it-very-hard-problem-to-determine-original-automorphism-from-composition-of-a

Comment: I made small edits to the new post @marlasca23 please mention what you think. Thanks a lot